# Extract SQLCODE from Exception pragma in oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

I am attempting to pass an error as a parameter to a procedure in PL/SQL. To do this, I am passing a number (error code) to the procedure. In a few cases, the error I am trying to pass is predefined and named using `EXCEPTION_INIT`, and I would like to use the name, but to do that I need to extract the number.

Is there a way to extract the number from a predefined exception?

```sql
-- A trivialized example of what I mean
DECLARE
  ex_bad_data    EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_bad_data, -20008);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error Code: '||get_the_err_code(ex_bad_data));
END;
```

**UPDATE**

The question was asked "why". I am trying to slowly refactor some code that has an "ignore exceptions" parameter. I am trying to change that to ignoring specified cases rather than a general ignore.

So instead of

```
procedure dosomething(ignore_errors boolean)
```

I now have

```
procedure dosomething(ignore_error number)
```

This will allow me to keep a lot of the calling code, while reducing my exposure to (potentially) hidden errors.

**UPDATE II**

I already have the code that accepts and ignores a condition. I was hoping to be able to use the exception names for clarity.

```
procedure dosomething(ignore_error number) 
begin
  -- do stuff here
exception
  when other then
    if(sqlcode <> ignore_error)then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
```

Current call:

```
dosomething(-2008);
```

Desired call:

```
dosometing(get_the_err_code(ex_bad_data));
```

So that people have a clear idea of what they are ignoring.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. Can you show more broadly (less trivialized) what you're trying to do? Is the idea to have a centralized error handling procedure (logging, etc..) that you call from exception handlers?

Comment: you can't do that.

Comment: `exception` isn't a datatype you can pass around. However, you can just refer to `sqlcode` within an exception handler and you've 'got the error code', so I'm not really seeing the point of this.

Comment: @PaulW I swear I saw an ASK TOM where that was demonstrated, but can't find it...at least this confirms my googling is not *that* bad, just my memory.

Comment: Also updated with explanation for "Why?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a perfect solution that let's you pass exception names to procedures, but if you use package constants and a disciplined coding style you may be able to accomplish the same goal of improving code clarity.

First, create a global package that contains the relevant exceptions. (Or, if this issue only applies to one package, then put this code in the top of the package body.) Since exceptions will be passed around, it helps to have a single place to store them. This also ensures that numbers are unique and follow a similar style. Notice that for each exception there is also a constant with the same name but with a suffix like "_NUMBER". The constant helps ensure the number is not repeated. But the variable names will require discipline to ensure there is consistency.

```
create or replace package custom_exceptions is
  exception1 exception;
  exception1_number constant number := -20001;
  pragma exception_init(exception1, exception1_number);

  exception2 exception;
  exception2_number constant number := -20002;
  pragma exception_init(exception2, exception2_number);

end;
/
```

Below is an example of a procedure that accepts error codes. This should work the exact same way you had envisioned.

```
create or replace procedure dosomething(ignore_error number) is
begin
  -- do stuff here
  null;
exception
  when others then
    if(sqlcode <> ignore_error)then
      raise;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Calling the procedure is only slightly different. Instead of calling it with `EXCEPTION1` as the argument, pass in `EXCEPTION1_NUMBER`.

```
begin
  dosomething(custom_exceptions.exception1_number);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_conditionally_ignore_exception(in_ignore_error number)
AS
  unhandled_exception exception;
  var_error_number number;
BEGIN
  var_error_number := SQLCODE;
  
  IF var_error_number IS NULL -- SQLCODE may not always populate in some situations
  THEN
    var_error_number := server_error(1);      -- returns the sqlcode but with a positive sign
    var_error_number := var_error_number*-1;  -- reverse the sign to negative
  END IF;
  
  IF in_ignore_error != SQLCODE
  THEN
    RAISE unhandled_exception;
  END IF;
END;
/

-- test1
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'adf';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_conditionally_ignore_exception(-20008);
END;
/

-- test2
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20008,'This should not be seen');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_conditionally_ignore_exception(-20008);
END;
/
```

The only downside is that this adds another exception to the error stack. If this is a PL/SQL app that is handling certain exceptions further up the stack, adding a new one could mess it up. Unfortunately the simple RAISE (which doesn't add to the stack) cannot be used outside of an immediate exception handler. But of course you could have the proc return a Boolean rather than raise an exception, and then use IF THEN in your exception handlers to then do a simple RAISE. But then you're getting to the point of having too much of the proc code repeated in each exception handler, which raises the question whether such a proc is useful at all.

Comment: That is (roughly) what I have. I was hoping to be able to use the existing exception names for code clarity

Comment: It's not elegant, but you could build an associative array of exceptions and codes from sourcecode and reference that, but scoping them would be quite difficult.

Comment: Yup, associative array, I think that's the solution... maintain an independent mapping. That's too bad.